# Python program treating dictionary like a string

Tags: python, dictionary

I set up a dictionary, and filled it from a file, like so:

```
filedusers = {} # cheap way to keep track of users, not for production
FILE = open(r"G:\School\CS442\users.txt", "r")
filedusers = ast.literal_eval("\"{" + FILE.readline().strip() + "}\"")
FILE.close()
```

then later I did a test on it, like this:

> if not filedusers.get(words[0]):

where `words[0]` is a string for a username, but I get the following error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

but I verified already that after the `FILE.close()` I had a dictionary, and it had the correct values in it.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: A better way to serialize would be using JSON: import json ; json.FILE.write(json.dumps(filedusers)) - eval is root of all kinds of evil

Comment: @Mikko, thanks, this is just to do some basic thing so I can work on the important code, no chance of using this for production.

Comment: But I can guarantee json works and it is part of stdlib since Python 2.6 :)

Comment: @agf, not sure what else you'd need, nothing else modifies `filedusers`, just some crappy socket code inbetween.  `words[0]` comes off of a spit statement from a decoded (utf-8) string.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa but `ast.literal_eval` is safe -- I'm not saying `json` is better or worse, but the security risks of `eval` aren't an issue.

Comment: @LanceRoberts yeah, I saw the error immediately after that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

literal_eval takes a string, and converts it into a python object. So, the following is true...

```
ast.literal_eval('{"a" : 1}')
>> {'a' : 1}
```

However, you are adding in some quotations that aren't needed. If your file simply contained an empty dictionary (`{}`), then the string you create would look like this...

```
ast.literal_eval('"{}"') # The quotes that are here make it return the string "{}"
>> '{}'
```

So, the solution would be to change the line to...

```
ast.literal_eval("{" + FILE.readline().strip() + "}")
```

...or...

```
ast.literal_eval(FILE.readline().strip())
```

..depending on your file layout. Otherwise, literal_eval sees your string as an ACTUAL string because of the quotes.

Comment: I endup getting the `malformed node or string:` error if I use the 'bracket-only' solution.  More Info: file contents like `'User1': Pass1,'User2': Pass2`.

Comment: This is because now the string ends up being "{'User1': Pass1,'User2': Pass2}", which is not correct python syntax. Pass1 and Pass2 must be quoted as well since they are strings. You need to change the file format, or use a different method to read it in.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import ast
>>> username = "asd: '123'"
>>> filedusers = ast.literal_eval("\"{" + username + "}\"")
>>> print filedusers, type(filedusers)
{asd} <type 'str'>
```

You don't have a dictionary, it just looks like one. You have a string.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed: it does not require you to define variables as a specific type.  And it lets you define variables implicitly.  What you are doing is defining `filedusers` as a dictionary, and then **redefining** it as a string by assigning the result of `ast.literal_eval` to it.

EDIT: You need to remove those quotes.  `ast.literal_eval('"{}"')` evaluates to a string.  `ast.literal_eval('{}')` evaluates to a dictionary.